# Trigger to Update fields on contact from the Account's opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger

Contact has a lookup Account.
Account has related record Opportunity.

When on contact record a Lookup account is selected. I want to update the contact fields with values of Opportunity fields which is related to the same account.

Account will only have 1 opportunity.

For example:

ContactRecord1 has lookup Account1 and Account1 has a related opportunity named Opportunity1. I want to update contact fields with opportunity fields.

```
trigger ConTest on Contact(before insert,before update,after update) {
    Set<ID> sObjConID = new Set<ID>();
    Set<ID> sObjAccID = new Set<ID>();
    Map<ID,ID> mapOppToCon = new Map<Id,ID>();
    Map<ID,ID> mapOFContactAccount = new Map<ID,ID>();
    For(Contact conSobj : Trigger.new){
        sObjConID.add(conSobj.ID);
        sObjAccID.add(conSobj.AccountId);
        mapOFContactAccount.put(conSobj.Id, conSobj.AccountId);
    }
    For(Opportunity sObjOppList : [Select id,oppField1__c,AccountID  from Opportunity  where AccountID IN:sObjAccID]){
        mapOppToCon.put(sObjOppList.AccountID,sObjOppList.ID);
        
    }
    
    
     }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working fine.

```
 trigger ContactUpdatefromOpp on Contact (before insert , before Update) {
            
       List<Contact> contactList1 = new List<Contact>();
        set<id> accids = new set<id>();
        If (trigger.IsBefore && (trigger.Isinsert ||trigger.Isupdate)){
            for(Contact con: Trigger.new){
               If(con.accountid !=null){
                 accids.add(con.accountid);
                }
            }
        }
        //here you can query list of opp fields you would require
    List<Opportunity> opplist = [select id,Accountid, name from opportunity where Accountid in:accids];
        
    if (opplist.size()>0){
        
    for (contact con: trigger.new)
       for(Opportunity opp:OppList){
           //here you can assign opp fields to contact fields 
           con.LastName=opp.Name;
    
         }
    
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Ankaiah this works for a single record but not in the bulk records. It updates the value of the last opportunity on all contacts which are mass updating.